# Minesweeper: How to fix "too many recursions" error?

Tags: python, pygame

So I coded a function for when the player clicks on a field with no mines around...
It should continue revealing all fields around that field until it is surrounded by numbers...

It should happen something like this:

[image]

I have shortened the code for you and the code I used at the beginning was:

```
def reveal_neighbours_of(cell: Cell) -> None:
        
    neighbours = get_neighbours_of(cell)

    for n in neighbours:
        if n.mines_around == 0:
            n.reveal()
            reveal_neighbours_of(n)
```

This led to an recursion overflow...
so I tried:

```
max_recursion_depth = 10
current_recursion_depth = 0
def reveal_neighbours_of(cell: Cell) -> None:
       
    neighbours = get_neighbours_of(cell)

    for n in neighbours:
        if n.mines_around == 0:
            n.reveal()
            if current_recursion_depth < max_recursion_depth:
                current_recursion_depth += 1
                reveal_neighbours_of(n)
```

But this would just ends at recursion depth of 10 even if there are more field to reveal...
Also The second code gives the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_recursion_depth' referenced before assignment
```

I really can't think of another way to make an algorithm for this problem...

Comment: If a cell uses `reveal_neighbours_of` on other nearby cells, won't they in turn call that function on the original cell, resulting in an infinite loop?

Comment: Going back to your original code.  Do you call reveal_neighbors_of(n) on a neighbor even it has already been revealed?  That's why you're getting infinite recursion. A reveals B reveals A reveals B reveals A....

Comment: The error was not the main problem but thank you anyway :-)

Comment: Oh god you are right... There is an infinite loop...

Comment: Please include your execution trace.  What calls did you make, with what parameters?  How did your base case miss terminating the recursion?  We expect you to provide the initial debugging attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop forever if you reveal two blank squares, as they go back and forth between eachother.

```
if n.mines_around == 0:
```

needs to check

```
if n.mines_around == 0 and not n.alreadyrevealedlogic()
```